# Trying to remove punctuation with AWK

Tags: awk

I have a script that I am trying to clean up the ~ from the fields.

```
awk '{gsub(/[[:punct:]]/, "")} 1' RS='[[:space:]]'/test/data/USER.FIDS
~qqq~
~jeff~
~mark~
```

This is how I would like to clean this up, and remove the Tilde from the fields.

```
qqq
jeff
mark
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for showing your efforts in your question(keep it up), could you please post samples of input and expected output in your question so that we can understand it better, thank you.

Comment: ~qqq~ ~jeff~ ~mark~    from this with the Tilde in front and back of the names.   To looking clean ...qqq   jeff   mark    No tilde showing up at all.

Comment: Note that if you want to remove certain character there is not need to use character class (`[:punct:]`) and this might give unwanted effect. For example think what if one of users is `~jane.done~`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awk is actually a more difficult solution. You actually want `sed` that makes the operation trivial, e.g.

```
sed 's/~//g'
```

Where `s/find/replace/` is the normal substitution form with `find` equal to `"~"` and `replace` with nothing (empty-string). The `g` makes the substitutions global (all occurrences).

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo "~qqq~ ~jeff~ ~mark~" | sed 's/~//g'
qqq jeff mark
```

Of course the `awk` solution is equally short, e.g.

```
awk '{gsub(/~/,"")}1'
```

Which does exactly the same thing using `gsub()` (global substitute).

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo "~qqq~ ~jeff~ ~mark~" | awk '{gsub(/~/,"")}1'
qqq jeff mark
```

Comment: You are quite welcome See the [GNU Awk User's Guide - String-Manipulation Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#String-Functions) for details on `gsub()` and all string functions (`awk` has a lot!) The `1` is just the default-print operation.

Answer (score 2):

even simpler with `tr`

```
$ echo "~qqq~ ~jeff~ ~mark~" | tr -d '~'

qqq jeff mark
```